# Access elements of an iframe using childView

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to extract all HTML elements of an iframe.

My iframe displays an HTML form.

I would like to retrieve the elements of the form using simple queries like `getElementsByClassName()`

```
<iframe style="width:100%;height:1000px;background-color: white;" [src]="generateUrl()" #iframe >
</iframe>
```

Code:

```
@ViewChild('iframe', {static: false}) iframe: ElementRef;

collectData() {
    const innerDoc = this.iframe.nativeElement.innerHTML;
    const cusid_ele = (innerDoc.getElementsByClassName('form-control'));
}
```

Comment: And what you have now is not working..?

Comment: You cannot access the data in an iframe if it is not on the same hostname `example.com` and `sub.example.com` are cross referenceable, but `example.com` and `google.com` are not, unless the item in the iframe allows this by setting its `location.hostname`

Comment: @MikeOne no it is not working it shows zero. If I try the same thing in dev tool; it shows something but other times it shows an enpty qrrqy: